# Generate all broadcast-able shapes from a given shape in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an array shape

eg - (10, 3)

I am looking for a function in numpy that can generate all possible shapes having at least 1 dimension, that can broadcast with the given shape.

output eg - [(1,), (3,), (1, 1), (1, 3), (10, 1), (10, 3)]

I know this can be done with python loops but I am looking for a better solution in numpy.

Comment: That output is a list of tuples of different lengths.  And only 6.  The fast numpy methods make large multidimensiomal arrays.  Why do you expect there to be something special for those?  I don't see any value in such a list, except for testing your own knowledge.

Comment: I have a use case for that output list. So, the take away is write down a function in python to do so?